# Permissions to htm file in root of SharePoint 2010 site

Tags: sharepoint

I created a simple HTM file in the root of our SharePoint site in SharePoint Designer.  It inherits permissions from its parent.  People who are not site collection administrators are getting the standard access denied message from SharePoint.

Looking at permissions, most everyone has permission to read the file.  All Authenticated Users has read access for the first thing.  I have a test user that gets the access denied message.  But when I log on as a site collection administrator, I am allowed to view the file.  The same test user can view siblings of the file I created without any problems.

We do not have anonymous access enabled.  This SharePoint 2010 environment uses claims based authentication through Shibboleth and ADFS.  I doubt that is relevant, but I thought I would share anyway.

What is going on?  I've poked around in the IIS, SharePoint and Windows Event logs without finding much.  Any ideas what I can try next to determine the source of my problem?  Or good ideas to try?

Answer (score 0):

Found that there was no major revision of this file published.  Once I did that, it began appearing for non-site collection administrator users.